# How can i test the performance of DOM manipulation code in JS

Tags: javascript, performance, dom

I want to test the performance of some code snippets in JS using:

```
function perf() {
  var start = new Date()
  // the snippet codes
  var end = new Date()
  return end - start
}
```

then i wrote some sample code:

HTML:

```
<section>
    <button>insert list item</button>
    <ul></ul>
</section>
```

JS:

```
function insertListItem() {
  let ul = document.querySelector('ul')
  let start = new Date()

  // heavy dom operations
  for (let i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    let li = document.createElement('li')
    li.textContent = 'item' + i
    ul.appendChild(li)
  }

  // log the duration (deferred by 0ms timer)
  setTimeout(() => {
    let t2 = new Date() - start
    console.log(`t2: ${t2} ms`)
  }, 0)

  // log the duration instantly
  let t1 = new Date() - start
  console.log(`t1: ${t1} ms`)
}

let N = 100000
let btn = document.querySelector('button')
btn.addEventListener('click', insertListItem)
```

The console output was:

`t1: 199 ms
t2: 7332 ms`

It looks like `t2` is the performance i want, but wrap them with a deferred timer is weird, what is right way to do this? And why is `t1` so fast?

Comment: I asked similar thing in SO, but without fortune, it doesn't get any answer. The above code can be run there too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42453937/dom-manipulation-performance-test

Answer (score 1):

Use Chrome's [Timeline tool](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/timeline-tool) to measure performance.

> - Make a Timeline recording to analyze every event that occurred after a page load or a user interaction.
> - View FPS, CPU, and network requests in the Overview pane.
> - Click on an event within the Flame Chart to view details about it.
> - Zoom in on a section of a recording to make analysis easier.